# sql php conect return value

Tags: php, sql

Well `mpost.php` works OK sends data to MySQL as new member when `checklogin.php` its not connecting. I have try everything on my knowledge but I got stuck
any other ideas?

My `db_name` , `password` and `table_name` its members as you can see on `mpost.php`.

```css
<?php
//this its members post mpost . php
define('DB_NAME', 'abcd');
define('DB_USER', 'abcd');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '******');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

 if (!$link)
{
die('Could NOT Connect: rong pass ' . mysql_error(rong_pass));
}
$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected) 
{
die ('Cant\'t use' . DB_NAME. 'abcd' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'log in succes';
$com_name = $_POST["com_name"]; 
$com_ger_nr = $_POST["com_reg_nr"];
$password = $_POST["password"];



$sql = "INSERT INTO members (com_name, com_reg_nr, password) VALUES                   
('$_POST[com_name]','$_POST[com_reg_nr]','$_POST[password]')";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die (" could not save record sorry ");

mysql_close();
?>
</ p><a href="demo.html">hey hey</a>

//tot odata ai fost adaugat in baza noastra de date
```

```html
<?php
// this its checklogin . php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="abcd"; // Mysql username 
$password="********"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="abcd"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("ups pula conectie"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("pula DB");

// username and password sent from, the form 
$com_name = $_POST["com_name"]; 
$com_reg_nr = $_POST["com_reg_nr"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_register("com_name");
session_register("com_reg_nr");
session_register("password"); 
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated and so try to use mysqli_* or PDO for this purpose. Also any error you are getting then show that one in your post .

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated (as above), session_register is deprecated (5.3) and removed as of 5.4 so I'd recommend against using that. $result isn't defined anywhere so that bit won't work. What error are you actually getting.

Comment: adding (i) did not work same error cod not connect to sql something to do with the connection i think

Comment: guys mpost.php works fine its registering the second code checklogin.php das not conect

Comment: What's the /exact/ error message.

Comment: row number 9 exact error message its (ups pula conectie)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
```

You forgot to select the database.

```
mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
```

Comment: no steal no, do you happen to have a 100% functional check login script and i will change it whit my data cause this one i got it from the WWW but looks like its not functional